# How to see the list of known hosts Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ssh, known-hosts

When I `ssh`ed into a remote client, I got a warning :

```
Warning: Permanently added 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Where can I see the list of known hosts?

I tried `cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts`, but this returns data in some hashed form. Does anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.ssh/known_hosts` in your case doesn't store plaintext hostnames, but rather hashed values of hostnames. Therefore you can't just list host names from it.

As answered in by [Cakemox](https://serverfault.com/users/50996/cakemox) the [this](https://serverfault.com/a/331085/492848) question, you can set `HashKnownHosts No` in your ssh configuration so that SSH stores hostnames instead of hashes.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do it by putting up this command

ssh-keygen -H -F (hostname) put in the name of the host.

Comment: Can you explain what do `-H` and `-F` options are meaning? I'm not sure this returns the content of ~/.ssh/known_hosts in a clear version.

Comment: This give the hashes of the given host name if it was in the `known_hosts` file, but not a proper answer to the question.